# Print 200 random number

Tags: algorithm, random

I have a function `getrand100()` which returns a random number from 0-100

Write a code snippet to print numbers 1-200 in a random order with none of them repeating.  You may call getrand100() any number of time to get random number from 1 to 100.

Please help how to do this?

Comment: You have defined both C and Java -- so, which one?

Comment: yes homework acually i am looking for logic so i will implements in either langauge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an array of numbers from 0 to 200. Then, use the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to shuffle them.

Since your `getrand100` function only gives numbers from 0 to 100, write something like this:

```
int rnd = getrand100();
int scale = getrand100();
if (scale >= 50)
    rnd += 100;
```

That will give you random numbers from 0 to 200.

Actually, it's a little more complicated than that because the range of random numbers changes. That is, at first you want to generate a random number from 0 to 200. The next time, from 0 to 199, then 198, 197, etc. So you need a way to scale your random numbers. Something like the following will get you reasonably close to uniform distribution:

```
int rnd = getrand100();
double frnd = rnd / 100.0;
int realRnd = round(frnd * range);
```

This assumes you have a rounding function. `range` is the top of your range. So the first call, `range` is 200, then 199, etc.

That won't give you perfect uniform distribution, since you'll only be working with two significant digits, but it will give an acceptable result for a classroom assignment.

Comment: @Hogan: Duplicates aren't a problem with the Fisher-Yates Shuffle. The   array is shuffled, and then output. Read the Wikipedia article.

Comment: The requirements.  The OP said there can't be duplicates, your answer does not solve that problem.

Comment: @Hogan: Using the Fisher-Yates shuffle, *there are no duplicates*. It doesn't matter what random numbers are generated, as they're not output. They're only used to shuffle the array. You really should read the linked Wikipedia article.

Comment: Mea culpa - Fisher Yates solves exactly this problem and using it "in place" is clearly the best way.  (Which is what I was thinking of without knowing the name.)

Answer (score 2):

Define `getrand200()` as `getrand100() + getrand100()`, since you've got no requirement of uniform distributions. Build an array of the numbers 1-200. Implement a skewed version of the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm using `getrand200`.